# how can i create an iframe and destroy the element only after the iframe has loaded?

Tags: javascript

i am able to create an iframe using appendChild, without jquery, is it possible for me to know when the iframe has loaded and then be able to destroy the element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `onLoad` event.

```
 <iframe onload="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" src="/"></iframe>
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mSZ4X/1/

Or by using pure JavaScript:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

iframe.src = "/";
iframe.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);    
};

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mSZ4X/2/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the iframe DOM element you created in the variable "myIframe", you can do something like this:

```
myIframe.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        myIframe.parentElement.removeChild(myIframe);
    }, 0);
}
```

The onload event will trigger when your iframe's content is loaded. You could call removeChild immediately in the onload handler, but I've seen some browser (Firefox I think) continue to think the iframe is loading if you remove it immediately. To combat that, just do the remove in a 0 millisecond setTimeout, the browser will call that code at it's next earliest convience.